# Dismiss Modally presented view makes tab bar controller (kind of) reset

Tags: ios, objective-c, modal-dialog, uitabbarcontroller, dismiss

I have an app which has tab bar controller as main controller. Each tab has a series of views with navigation controller and I normal push and pop those view in stack.

Weird problem is

Case 1 : If I create a UINavigationController and make a new viewController as its root, and present this NavigationController. Within this new navigation stack, I can easily present a view modally and dismiss it without a problem.

Case 2: Now without make a new UINavigationController, I present a view, and when I dismiss a view, the view beneath is behave weirdly. For example, it's the presenting view was UICollectionView, it just scroll back to 1st cell, like it's doing "reload" action and "scrollTo" the first cell. If the presentingView is a pushed view from rootView, it will just popToRoot view, which is definitely not intended.

I didn't have this problem until I implement UITabbarController, so I guess, I should know more that's going on under the hood when presenting a view and dismiss a view in UITabbarController.

I GUESS, when dismiss a view in UITabbarController view, it sort of "RESET" everything to the very first view of it's current tab. I really am not sure it's trure though.

I know it's kind of conceptual, but I can't help to think there must be something critical I am missing here.

Answer (score 8):

I made silly mistake that I sublclass UITabbarController and define navigation controlllers in viewDidAppear instead viewdidLoad, so when I make the window's rootview to tabbar controller, the navigation controllers are not set properly. That's why all punky things happened. It would be nicer if just crash instead of this weird behaviors.

Comment: This is great!! I made the same silly mistake and didn't realize it until i read your post. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Same mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this to go back to your first viewcontroller.

```html
- (IBAction)buttonPressedFromVC2:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
} // This is going back to VC1.
```

This method is will be in second viewcontroller.m file. It is button click method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's not a question about how to dismiss a view. Dismiss a view is fine, the the presenting viewcontroller behave wierdly after dismissing modally presented view.